# Some Wolfram|Alpha Features I can't achieve in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, series-expansion, summation, wolfram-alpha-queries

I have noticed some features available on the site Wolfram|Alpha which I am not managing to replicate. Two examples which come to mind are the following.

1. Given a function $f(x)$, I want to determine its Taylor series, and its **radius of convergence** also. For example, take $f(x)=\ln(1-x^2)$. On Wolfram|Alpha, I get the following output:

   > [image: Figure 1]

   where I get the nice "*converges when $|x|<1$*" detail below. I know that I can obtain the series by running the command `Series[Log[1-x^2], {x,0,8}]`, but I don't know how to get the radius of convergence. The inbuilt command `SumConvergence` does not allow one to determine the radius, since the general term of the series must be known.
2. Suppose we have a homogeneous system of linear equations represented by the matrix equation $\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf0$, e.g. $$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
     3&2&1\\7&6&k\\k&4&3
     \end{pmatrix}}_{\mathbf A}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
   Both the `Solve` and `LinearSolve` commands give only the trivial solution $x=y=z=0$ as the solution to the system. But the website gives the interesting ones too:

   > [image: Figure 2]

There are a few other situations where I have found the site more useful than the application - but so far these two have been the most frustrating. Is there any way to achieve the two above in Mathematica without having to go online?

---

**EDIT**  For 2, I attempted to use `Reduce` by running the following code.

```
Reduce[{
 {3, 2, 1},
 {7, 6, k},
 {k, 4, 3} } . {x,y,z} == {0, 0, 0}]]
```

but got the following (better, but still not as good) output:

```
(z == 0 && y == 0 && x == 0) || ((y == -2 z || y == -((5 z)/4)) && x == 1/3 (-2 y - z) && y != 0 && k == (10 (2 y + z))/(3 y))
```

Comment: As per 2. - use `Reduce`.

Comment: @corey979 I actually tried that, and got the output `(z == 0 && y == 0 && x == 0) || ((y == -2 z || y == -((5 z)/4)) && 
   x == 1/3 (-2 y - z) && y != 0 && k == (10 (2 y + z))/(3 y))`, but this is less informative (no $z\neq 0$, and no values of $k$ for which the solutions work).

Comment: I've got something different that includes the `k`. Edit your question and include the codes you are using as well as their output.

Comment: @corey979 What do you think?

Comment: You have a redundant bracket. I did `LogicalExpand@
 Reduce[{{3, 2, 1}, {7, 6, k}, {k, 4, 3}}.{x, y, z} == {0, 0, 0}, {x, 
   y, z}]`

Comment: @corey979 Ah, I needed to add the `{x,y,z}` parameter to get the outputs for $k$. Thanks. Any ideas about 1?

Comment: No. And I need to write this sentence to exceed the limit of 15 characters for a comment to say it to you.

Comment: How about FunctionDomain `f[x_] := Log[1 - x^2]; FunctionDomain[f[x], x]` for the region of definition?

Comment: Try `With[{c = Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[Log[1 - x^2], {x, 0, n}], n > 0]}, FullSimplify[SumConvergence[c x^n, n]]]` for the first one. For the second one, this might help: `mat = {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 6, k}, {k, 4, 3}}; MapAt[NullSpace, {k, mat} /. Solve[Det[mat] == 0, k], {All, 2}]`.

Answer (score 2):

To shed some light why Mathematica only gives the trivial NullSpace for example 2 in post, I solved this by hand and this is what I found:

$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1\\
7 & 6 & k\\
k & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

To find the null space, we solve for $x$ in $Ax=0$. Applying Gaussian elimination

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1\\
7 & 6 & k\\
k & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\overset{R_{2}=R_{2}-\frac{7}{3}R_{1}}{\underset{R_{3}=R_{3}-\frac{k}{3}
R_{1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & \frac{4}{3} & k-\frac{7}{3}\\
0 & 4-\frac{2}{3}k & 3-\frac{k}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now $R_{3}=R_{3}-\frac{\left(  4-\frac{2}{3}k\right)  }{\frac{4}{3}}R_{2}$  gives

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & \frac{4}{3} & k-\frac{7}{3}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}k^{2}-\frac{9}{2}k+10
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Last row gives

$$
\left(  \frac{1}{2}k^{2}-\frac{9}{2}k+10\right)  z=0
$$

Two cases to consider in (1)

**case 1** If $\frac{1}{2}k^{2}-\frac{9}{2}k+10\neq0$ then $z=0$.
Second row now gives $\frac{4}{3}y+\left(  k-\frac{7}{3}\right)  z=0$, or
$y=0$. First row gives $x=0$. Hence in this case the NullSpace is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**case 2**  If $\frac{1}{2}k^{2}-\frac{9}{2}k+10=0$, then $z=t$, a
free parameter, which can be any value. Second row in (1) now gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{4}{3}y+\left(  k-\frac{7}{3}\right)  t  & =0\\
y  & =-\frac{3}{4}t\left(  k-\frac{7}{3}\right)
\end{align*}
And first row gives

\begin{align*}
3x+2y+z  & =0\\
3x  & =-2\left(  -\frac{3}{4}t\left(  k-\frac{7}{3}\right)  \right)  -t\\
x  & =\frac{1}{2}t\left(  k-3\right)
\end{align*}

Hence in this case, the NullSpace is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=t
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\left(  k-3\right)  \\
-\frac{3}{4}\left(  k-\frac{7}{3}\right)  \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since $\frac{1}{2}k^{2}-\frac{9}{2}k+10=0$, the solution is $k=5,k=4$.
Substituting these values into the above gives the NullSpace as

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=
t\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{5}{4}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$

For any $t$. For only $t=0$, this gives the result gives by Mathematica.

So  Wolfram Mathematica only considered the case 1 above, and did not
consider case 2.  Wolfram Alpha, which has additional A.I. engine, seems to have looked more into this.

Comment: Here's how to use *Mathematica* for constructing the reduced form: `UpperTriangularize[First[LUDecomposition[{{3, 2, 1}, {7, 6, k}, {k, 4, 3}}]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you.

Comment: @J.M. btw, this only works for square matrices. For non-square matrices, I had to write an M function to do this.

Comment: Indeed, it is unfortunate that *Mathematica* does not have something built-in for performing Gaussian elimination on rectangular matrices.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was intersted in case 2, and particularly the values of k.